# How to deploy custom webpart from one server to another in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I can't find any answers on how to deploy my custom webpart from one SharePoint 2010 Server to another SharePoint 2010 Server.

I have a farm solution custom-webpart developed in SharePoint 2010 and I want to move to my webpart to a different environement.

Can anybody give me step-by-step like how to deploy?

thanks.

PS: VS2010, SP2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Add-SPSolution fullpathtoWSP
Install-SPSolution –Identity NameOfWSP –WebApplication http://WebAppurl -GACDeployment

(give it time to deploy across the farm - you can check this status in Central Admin)

Enable-SPFeature -Identity "FeatureName" -Url http://SiteOrWebUrlForFeature
```

Answer (score 0):

You can package and deploy the web part as WSP

http://leedale.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/deploying-a-webpart-solution-in-sharepoint-2007-the-simple-way/