# Deployed Sharepoint 2010 WebPart, but where is it?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Followed the steps in the answer to this question: [How to deploy custom webpart from one server to another in sharepoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271052/how-to-deploy-custom-webpart-from-one-server-to-another-in-sharepoint-2010)

It all seemed to work ok, but now what do I do? If I 'edit' the home page of the sharepoint site and click "Add Web PArt", I don't see it in the list.

I am a complete newbie when it comes to Sharepoint, so simple steps would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Part definition files have to be in the *Web Part Gallery* in order to be available in the "Add Web Part List".

You can create a SharePoint site feature to deploy the definition files in this library:

**feature.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
    Id="DFD20610-C329-45E0-B037-8E6FC0A684AB"
    Title="Web Part Feature"
    Scope="Site"
    >

    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="Elements.xml" />
        <ElementFile Location="TheWebPart.dwp" />
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

**Elements.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="WebPartPopulation" Url="_catalogs/wp" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
        <File Path="TheWebPart.dwp" Url="TheWebPart.dwp" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
            <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've got a Feature.xml and Elements.xml along with a .webpart file in my visual studio project file that match the definitions above.  Do I just do "Upload document" with these files into the All Web Parts page?

Comment: Ok, took a guess and uploaded the .webpart file and now I can see it in the list. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, if the web part definition file is in the wsp solution, the file should be uploaded automatically on feature activation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. First, the Path and Url attributes of the File element in Elements.xml must specify the module as well as the filename (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567.aspx). Once I do that it still doesn't work - I can see an item in the web part gallery but it does not have a file extension or a group. It cannot be added to a web part page and preview fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Module line within Elements.xml also needs to contain **List="113"**